# Why is php error_log() writing to wrong file since yum update?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

yum update appears to have broken error_log setting in php.

We have this in .htaccess:

```
php_value error_log "/var/log/httpd/php_error.log"
```

It is reported correctly by phpinfo(), but error_log() is writing to /var/log/error_log as per httpd.conf

yum update did this:

```
php72w* 7.2.27-1.w7 -> 7.2.31-2.w7
httpd* 2.4.6-90.el7.centos -> 2.4.6-93.el7.centos
```

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod 755 /var/log/httpd
```

fixed it. Weirdly apache was writing its logs as root, but php was writing them as apache.